# Using MPI package not as a shared object

Tags: g++, mpi

I have a program composed of:

1. A package in C++.
2. A library in C.

The package in C++ uses the MPI package. it is required that the MPI will be used as a static and not as a shared object.
I use the mpic++ compiler.

I compile using the command mpic++ -static.

The error message after the compilation CAN NOT BE USED MAKING A PIE OBJECT:: failure to set dynamic section sizes: bad value.

I tried to recompile with:

1. fPIE
2. -fPIC

The error messages related to the MPI packes during link remained.